# Only when the stored procedure is ran twice it returns a full result set

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I execute the following stored procedure to get the *descendants* of a specific `folder id`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_get_folder_structure`(
    I_folder_id VARCHAR(100),
    I_user_id INT,
    I_sys_id INT
)
BEGIN

    SELECT id, parent_id, root, name, quotum, owner, fullpath, createdon, editedon FROM
        (SELECT id, parent_id, root, name, quotum, owner, fullpath, createdon, editedon,
                CASE WHEN id = I_folder_id THEN @idlist := CONCAT(id)
                     WHEN FIND_IN_SET(parent_id,@idlist) THEN @idlist := CONCAT(@idlist,',',id)
                END as checkId
         FROM folders WHERE sys_id = I_sys_id) as T 
    WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY id = I_folder_id DESC, parent_id ASC, name ASC LIMIT 100;
END
```

When I execute this code on the MySQL Workbench it only gives back a full result set after executing the query twice, the first time it only returns one row:
[image: full result set]

I'm baffled why this is happening. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the value of `@idlist` is different before the first and the second run. Why not try to create a procedure without the `@idlist` or make sure it is initialised?